# El arreglo solo me devuelve el último valor

Tags: php, array

Siempre me devuelve el último valor de la ejecución, y necesito que me muestre los datos con respecto al cupón seleccionado en el `dropdown`.

Como se puede ver, selecciono el cupón en el `option value` y este me muestra por pantalla el nombre del cupón, pero quiero que me cargue los datos que ya tiene en un formulario de modificación.

Aquí el selector más la query y el `for`:

```php
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Cupones</label>
    <select name="id" class="form-control select2" style="width: 100%;" required="true">
        <option value="">-- Seleccione el kupom --</option>
        <?php
        $sql = "SELECT id, destacado, cantidad, titulo, texto, duracion FROM cupones";
        $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute();
        $cupones = $stmt->fetchAll();
        for ($i = 0; $i <= count($cupones) - 1; $i++) {
            ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $cupones[$i]['id'] ?>"><?php echo $cupones[$i]['titulo'] ?></option>
            <?php
            if ($cod === $cupones[$i]['id']) {
                $cod = $cupones[$i]['id'];
                $des = $cupones[$i]['destacado'];
                $can = $cupones[$i]['cantidad'];
                $tit = $cupones[$i]['titulo'];
                $tex = $cupones[$i]['texto'];
                $dur = $cupones[$i]['duracion'];
            }
        }
        ?>
        ?>
    </select>
</div>
```

Aquí el campo de prueba, donde debería mostrarme la cantidad de cupones disponibles que hay, dependiendo del que yo escoja en el selector, pero siempre me muestra la cantidad del último elemento en la tabla y se queda ahí nomás, a pesar de que escoja otro cupón.

```php
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Cantidad de Kupones</label>
    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="cantidad" value="<?php echo $can;?>" name="cantidad" required="true">
</div>
```

Comment: Amigo, el único error que veo es de lógica: Si necesitas mostrar todos los datos de un objeto (en este caso *kupom*), deberías agregar dicha información a un listado. En el ciclo que creaste, cada que vez que recorres los elementos, al mismo tiempo los vas reemplazando, **NO LOS GUARDAS**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lo primero que te recomendaría es que no usases la función `count()` dentro de un `for`, ya que es una mala practica, mejor iguala el `count($array)` a una variable y usa esa variable para el `for` o también puedes usar un `foreach`, en este caso lo vería mas apropiado.

Referente a tu pregunta, lo que yo entiendo que quieres hacer es que ¿cada vez que cambies de opción en el `select`, cambie el valor del `input` con `id` **cantidad**?

Si esto es así, necesitas leer un poco sobre `AJAX`, ya que lo que necesitas es detectar el evento del cambio de opción en el `select` con `javascript` y mediante una llamada `AJAX` ejecutar un archivo .`php` en el servidor que te devuelva la cantidad asignada a ese cupón en la base de datos.

Siento no poder ser mas explicito pero es que abarca demasiado tu pregunta.

Un saludo!